# Obj-C: Delegation pattern, setting self as delegate

Tags: ios, uitableview, delegates

I have a custom TableView Cell that I use in a tableView - I have decided that I need to delegate some of its methods to the tableViewController.

```
//Custom tableview cell
typedef enum {
    kButtonSelected,
    kButtonNormal
} ButtonState;

// Classes using this custom cell must implement these methods
@protocol CustomTableViewCellDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void) storeButtonState:(ButtonState)state forButton:(UIButton *)sender;
- (void) restoreButtonState:(UIButton *)tagLectureButton;

@end

@interface CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

// Delegate
@property (assign) id <CustomTableViewCellDelegate> delegate;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *mainLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *numberLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *tagLectureButton;
```

Then I set the TableView to be its delegate and implement the methods. So far so good

```
@interface LecturesSubTVC : LecturesTVC <CustomTableViewCellDelegate>
```

But I do not have an instance variable to set `(self.CustomTableViewCell.delegate = self;)`

all the cells are allocated within methods like this:

```
CustomTableViewCell *cell = (CustomTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

How do I get to set the cell as delegate so the delegated methods gets called?

Comment: A side note: strictly, this looks more like a "data source" role than "delegate". Delegates make decisions and take action on behalf of their delegators: "Should I restore the button state?" "I just restored the button state. Anything that needs to be done in reaction?" and so on.

Comment: @Josh! I store the state of the button in the TableViewController using NSUserDefaults - it´s just either on or off. It just seems simple this way

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have everything in place. After dequeueing a cell in

```
CustomTableViewCell *cell = (CustomTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

just set its delegate with `cell.delegate = self;`

Answer (score 1):

```
CustomTableViewCell *cell = (CustomTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
cell.delegate = self;
```